# jqPlot in dynamically generated div

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jqplot

I generate a div inside one of jquery functions and now I want to make a jqPlot chart inside. It is declared like this `var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart_div', [chart1]`..... As chart_div is created later it's not in the DOM. I don't know how to use here something like `.live()` or `.on()`.